# The new line appears before the old line when writing to a file

Tags: c, file-io

In this program I am trying to input text data on a file, but it is not writing properly.

In my main, where I get data I have...

```
FILE *fp1 = NULL;
fp1 = fopen("accounts.dat", "a+");

printf ("\nEnter an account number (between 1000 and 5999): ");
        accounts[i] = validateaccount();

printf ("Enter title for new account %d: ", accounts2[i]);
        validatestring(accname, &i);
        scan(accounts, accname, &i);
```

Where "validateaccount()" and "validatestring()" call other functions which is where I get the account / string value. In the

```
scan(accounts, accname, &i);
```

function I am writing the value given from the validate functions into my file.

```
void scan (int accounts[MAX], char accname[MAX][MAXSTRING], int *i) {

FILE *fp1;

fp1 = fopen("accounts.dat", "a+");

fprintf(fp1, "%d", accounts[*i]);
fprintf(fp1, ":");
fprintf(fp1, "%s\n", accname[*i]);


}
```

So the format for my file input should be like

```
1000:First
1200:Second
```

If my account # was 1000, and the name was "First". And the 2nd account inputed was 1200, and "Second"

But what I get is something like:

```
1200:Second
1000:First
```

When I 'cat accounts.dat' ..the 2nd input is ahead of my first input. Why is this?

---

The problem was that I was doing

```
fp1 = fopen("accounts.dat", "a+");
```

every time I called the function when I could have just passed the argument in the file call, after I got rid of that it worked properly.

Fixed it.

Comment: Why do you open the file twice, and not just pass the `FILE*` into your `scan` method?

Comment: Is that done by, when I call the scan function: scan(accounts, accname, &i, *****) where ***** is the file call? If so, what is the correct parameter to replace the **** with?

Comment: Pass in the `FILE*` with something like `scan(accounts, accname, &i, fp1)`, where the last argument to `scan` is `FILE* fp1`. I'm not sure this solves your problem, but you shouldn't be opening the file twice. You should also remember to `fclose` your file pointer when you're done with it.

Comment: You need to use `fseek` in your program.

Comment: I passed the file into the functions, this should help make the code cleaner, but this does not fix the original problem I am having

Comment: @user1877276 Did what I say solve the problem? You said in a comment that it didn't, but said in an edit that it did.

Comment: no i was just saying that it didn't fix what I was trying to fix, and the edit was a different change that I made but your post did help me realize my mistake